# How to read file using the overload operator>>?

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have the following class with some private string:

```
class data{
 public:
    friend istream &operator>>(istream&, data&);
 private:
   string firstname;
  string lastname;
  string phonenum;
}
```

So, what is the right way to use the overload to read in my string from file. Here is my code. I had researched and seen people using getline. But when I use getline for my private data, it print out the whole different string.

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, data &r)
{
  // write this to read data object data
  in.ignore();
  in >> r.firstname;
  in >> r.lastname;
  in >> r.phonenum;
  return in;

}
int main(){
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("list1.txt"); // open file.txt
  string line;
  vector<data> A;
  data din;
  while (inFile >> din){
    A.push_back(din);
    cout << din << endl;                // to print out if this read
  }
  inFile.close(); 
}
```

The file. First name, last name and phone number

```
CANDACE WITT            250-939-5404
THEODORE PERKINS        723-668-3397
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need `in.ignore();`? What is the format of your file?

Comment: I don't know why I used it there? Maybe because it has strings so I put it there to clear out the new line. I will at the format file @RetiredNinja

Comment: If you don't know why the code is there then it shouldn't be there. What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: So after I read in the data into the <vector> and try to use stable_sort (A.begin(), A.end()) to sort my din. then I try to print again to see if it working. I wasn't so I wonder if I read in the data wrong @RetiredNinja

Comment: It sounds like you don't know where the problem is. Break your code down into small steps and test each one. Try reading one item from the file and verifying it worked. Then read more to fill up the vector and verify that worked, etc. When you find what actually isn't working then edit your question to include those details and a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @AnPhan you probably meant to call `in.ignore()` AFTER reading `phonenum`, to consume the line break that follows it. Another option (and what I would do) is to read the whole line into a `std::string` using `std::getline()`, then use `std::istringstream` to read the values out of the `std::string`.